# Do the destination tickets in Ticket To Ride require that the player completes the routes, or only that the tickets are completed?

Tags: ticket-to-ride

In other words, if the two cities are connected, is that sufficient for gaining the points on the destination ticket, or does the holder of the destination ticket have to connect the two cities using his own trains?

I have read over the official rules but it does not seem to be explicit about it.

I would appreciate a citation for answers if possible.

Comment: While your question has already been excellently answered, I wanted to note that if you're interested in a rail game that's 'track-agnostic' you might want to have a look at TransAmerica: http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2842/transamerica

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The holder of the destination card has to connect the two cities with their own trains. The route can be as roundabout as you like though, as long as they are connected.

In the Ticket to Ride: Europe version, you can build stations which then let you count another player's route as if it was your own for the purposes of scoring destination cards.

Comment: I concur. As for citations, I have three. 1) The rules say that players get points if *they* complete a series a routes that connects the cities on their tickets. There's no mention of include routes completed by other players. 2) There would be no use for Stations in the Europe version if you could include other people's routes. 3) I played with [François Valentyne](http://www.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/maps/asia/).

Answer (score 10):

The holder of the destination cards must connect the cities.  The [rules](https://ncdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/tt_rules_2015_en.pdf) are explicit about this (emphasis mine).

> Each Destination Ticket includes the name of two cities on the map and a Point Value.  If **a player** successfully completes a series of routes that connect
>   the two cities, **they** will add the amount of points indicated on the Destination Ticket to their point totals at the end of the game. If they do not
>   successfully connect the two cities, **they** deduct the amount of points indicated.
>
> **Players** should then reveal all their Destination Tickets and add (or subtract) the value of their Destination Tickets still in hand, based on whether
>   **they** successfully (or not) connected those cities together.

At no point is there any suggestion that players score points if any other player completes the route(s).